# How to install packages from scoped registries on older versions of Unity?

Tags: unity

- I have a Unity project using v2018.2 (I cannot update it)
- I need a package (namely, keijiro's [OscJack](https://github.com/keijiro/OscJack)) which must be installed using a scoped registry
- Scoped registries don't seem to have been a thing for Unity v2018.2

Is there a way that I can fetch it from the scoped registry anyway, or somehow generate a .unitypackage file from it so that I can import it as a custom package?

Comment: Can you add the package to an empty project in a newer version of Unity and then copy the files to your 2018 project?

Comment: Thanks for that idea. I tried it, but, at least for this package, it couldn't find the OscJack namespace in scripts. It seems like the file structure for how Unity stores packages has changed since v2018 making a manual adding of a package non-trivial. I will keep investigating